# Can I insert a prepositional phrase between an attributive clause and its antecedent?

Tags: grammar

For example:

```
He eats an apple which I picked yesterday.
```

If I want to modify the apply by a prepositional phrase, can I say:

```
He eats an apple above the table which I picked yesterday.
```

If I can't, how can I express the same meaning within one sentence?

Comment: You picked a table yesterday? Putting the adjective clause immediately following the word "table" implies exactly that.

Comment: */??He wants a basket for a large dog which is made out of wicker. // He eats an apple (which I picked yesterday) above the table.

Answer (score 1):

You've constructed a [dangling modifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_modifier) that leaves doubt about what got picked yesterday.

We can tie down that modifier with some punctuation.

`He eats an apple, above the table, which I picked yesterday.`

Parenthetical commas indicate that you can remove "above the table" and still have a meaningful sentence.